# Number of divisor?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

```
     import math 

     # function to count the divisors 
     def countDivisors(n) : 
        cnt = 0
        for i in range(1, (int)(math.sqrt(n)) + 1) : 
    i       if (n % i == 0) : 
          
        # If divisors are equal, 
        # count only one 
                 if (n / i == i) : 
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                 else : # Otherwise count both 
                    cnt = cnt + 2
              
      return cnt 
  
     # Driver program to test above function */ 

     print("Total distinct divisors of 100 are : ", 
                   countDivisors(100))
```

This code gives 9 as the total number of divisors. To make Time complexity O(n1/3) I didn't get the 2nd if condition. Can someone please explain What does that doing?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (n / i == i) :
```

If you encounter i, which iXi equals to your input n, (for example,when i=10, 100=10X10), then `cnt` is only incremented by 1, because you have only one distinct divisor in this case.

```
else : # Otherwise count both 
                cnt = cnt + 2
```

For other i, for example, when i=2, =>100/i !=2, you can say that 100 has two distinct divisors, 2 and 50. Therefore you can increment `cnt` by 2.

Comment: Ohh yeah I got it Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `n = 100`.

If `(n / i != i)`, it means you found a common divisor of `n`, for example, 4. Then, you know that 100 = 4 * 25, so you add 2 new divisors of 100 (4 and 25). This is where `cnt = cnt + 2` comes from.

But when `(n / i == i)`, it means `i` is the square root of 100 (if `n / i == i`, means `n == i * i`, hence `i` is the square root of `n`). The square root is a single divisor, so you just add it once (`cnt = cnt + 1`).